Automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}_{adgp}$
I am trying to find all the automorphisms of the $L$-structure $\mathbb{Q}_{adgp} = \langle\mathbb{Q},+,-,0\rangle$. I think I have the answer: $\pi(q) = pq, \ p \in \mathbb{Q}-\{0\}$, but this raises two questions:

I think I should prove that every automorphism is of this form, and I don't even know how to tackle this.
Is there any restrictions in the functions I am using in the structure? So for example I could use as an embedding from $\mathbb{Z}_{adgp}$ to $\mathbb{R}_{adgp}$ something related to the imaginary part of the non-trivial zeros of the Riemann Zeta function, even though it has little to do with the structures we are talking about. In my solution I am using multiplication of rationals to define a function on the structure that has only addition.


You need $p\neq0.$

True, I fixed it

hint for question 1: suppose $\pi$ is an automorphism of your structure, and let $p=\pi(1)$. can you figure out $\pi(n)$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$? if so, can you use that to figure out $\pi(q)$ for arbitrary $q$?

For question 2: No. The language restricts what functions are definable, but here we're talking about automorphisms of the structure, which are not required to be definable. Feel free to talk about the Riemann Zeta function! (Though it won't help you much with this exercise.)

I think I got it. Let $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$. If $q = 1/m$, then $\pi (q) = p/m$ (using the answer to your hint).  For a general $q = n/m$ we have that $\pi (q) = n\cdot p/m = pq$

Thanks to the comments, I think I have it.

Let $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and suppose $\pi(1) = p$. If $q = 1/m$, we have that $\pi(1) = m\cdot \pi(1/m) \implies \pi(1/m) = p/m$. For a general $q = n/m$, we have that $\pi(q) = n\cdot \pi(1/m) = n\cdot p/m = p\cdot q$
Definable functions are the functions that can be defined using L-formulas from the L-structure. In this case we are talking about morphisms of structures, so we don't need these functions to be definable.

